Is the normalization $S_2$ as an $R$-module?

Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring for which the normalization $\bar{R}$ is a finite $R$-module. Then is $\bar{R}$ $S_2$ as an $R$-module?

We know that $\bar{R}$ is $S_2$ as a ring (i.e. as a module over itself) because it is normal. But it is not clear if that implies it is $S_2$ as an $R$-module. I ask because I have seen it used that the $S_2$-ification of $\bar{R}$ is $\bar{R}$.
If no, what if we add some conditions to $R$ such as Cohen-Macaulay and excellent?
